# Is it possible to use IPv6 in my local network if my ISP is using IPv4

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6

My ISP is using IPv4 and assigns IP addresses via DHCP. Is it possible for me to use IPv6 in my local network/subnet, and if so is it even worth it to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's possible here is list of tunnel broker provider :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers

If your ISP does not route IPv6 packet to you. There are many solutions that can help you to serve IPv6 and access IPv6 network.
In my case I have a public IPv4 address which make me able to use 6in4 served by Hurricane Electric.

```
6in4 encaplsulate IPv6 packet in IPv4.
```

Here is the list of solution that you can use
**`6in4, tsp, ayiya, heartbeat, rdns, bgp, multicast`**

For more information about the adequate solution please refer to the link above.
In IPv6 there are no NAT, if you assign IPv6 addresses to your local nodes they will be reachable from outside, so your have to set a firewall to secure access to your LAN.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to use IPV6 in my local network/subnet?

- Yes, infact your local network's router most likely already does handle internal ipv6 routing.

> is it even worth it to do so?

- Subjective ... it all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  If you are just planning on using it for home use aka hooking up the occasional laptop / cell to wifi ... most likely not.  If you are working with device with IPV6 capability or possibly something that only supports ipv6 (some newer IoT devices) it might be worth while setting up.